# Can I reattatch the parts of my Canon 50mm f/1.8 lens which broke in a fall, without further disassembly?

Tags: lens, canon, repair, diy

[image]The upper part of my Canon **EF 50mm f/1.8 II** Lens is separated from the lens body due to a fall.

One of its 4 lugs has broken off. Can I still attach the upper and the lower parts without disassembling the whole lens?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Pictures would be helpful.  But most likely answer is no.  Even if you could, there might be other damage that would prevent the lens from working properly.  Learn from the experience, and take appropriate precautions to avoid dropping equipment in the future.

Comment: What do you mean by "upper?" The mount end or the front of the lens? Something else?

Comment: This is a photography site, so.... photograph the problem if you still have any lens left.

Comment: [Upper part of lens.](https://i.imgur.com/Wd6PmGk.png)

Comment: Looks worse than I'd imagined before you added the image.  But hard to tell because DOF is too shallow.

Comment: This might help a bit, but messing around the inside of lenses is a _tricky_ business. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15tUQhVMScc

Comment: @FábioDias - "Messing around the inside of [modern autofocus] lenses is a tricky business." Old manual-focus primes can be pretty straight-forward.

Comment: @xiota I had followed the video and the pdf from the same person before posting here. sadly he/she suggests dismantling the whole thing and not a part of it, which I was hoping for.

Comment: Plastic lenses are often not worth trying to fix.  Best option is to get a different lens.

Answer (score -1):

One of the best price/performance lens and  even does not need to fall off. Price of repairing it exceedes it's own price. Try to glue parts to fix together and then use it with reversal adapter for  macro photography.

Comment: though - sadly - it is not a solution, it is an interesting suggestion and can prove to be an excellent workaround if it actually works. I need to search for a reversal adapter. Can you recommend one for Canon 50mm 1.8 prime? Thanks!

Comment: 52mm Macro Reverse Adapter Ring for CANON EOS EF Mount

See also:

https://www.quora.com/Are-Canon-50mm-1-8-lenses-good-for-macro-photography

https://www.digitalphotomentor.com/turn-your-50mm-lens-into-macro-lens-under-20